# FHIR-Server-for-Azure deployment & debugging

Tags: hl7-fhir, fhir-server-for-azure

I am setting up a new open source FHIR Server (https://github.com/Microsoft/fhir-server) in Azure portal and would like to fully understand the code base structure. What is the best tooling? Can VS Prof. recognise the directory structure and allow full remote debugging?

Answer (score 1):

The open source code base has a Visual Studio solutions file in there. The development team uses Visual Studio to debug and develop the code base. That said, you don't need Visual Studio, if you install the .NET Core SDK, you can just run the project (and debug) from the command line and use whatever code editor you prefer. Visual Studio Code is also a popular choice for people working with the code base and it you can debug and so on using that.

When you say remote debugging, are you talking about debugging it while it is running in a Web App? It should be possible, but it is not a workflow that is used a lot. It is usually easier to run it locally while developing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and I have now loaded it in VS. It is quite an impressive piece of work.

Comment: I don't fully understand the design but would like to and possibly contribute. Could you possibly point me to external presentations or videos explaining the design and layers?. One of the things I don't understand is the pattern used to manage / populate the FHIR resources. e.g. although I can create & retrieve MedicinalProduct or SubstanceSubstance from the datastoreI can't find a class definition for  either.

Comment: The POCO classes for the specific FHIR resources come from the .NET FHIR API Model (http://docs.simplifier.net/fhirnetapi/model/classes.html). Those classes don't exists in the fhir-server itself.

Comment: Have located and loaded the POCO classes. Another piece of the jigsaw in place:-)

Comment: Going back to my easier question on debugging. You mention "It is usually easier to run it locally while developing". Could you pls elaborate how this is done? I've loaded the complete code base using the solutions file  into VS 2019. There were failures until I updated the sdk version to v2.2.401, (i think the git version is v2.2.108). When I try to run with debugging, a dos window is launched and then exits with unknown error. Should I be running a subset of the code base?  I am not very experienced with VS 2019.

Comment: You pick a web project to run, e.g. Microsoft.Health.Fhir.R4.Web if you want the R4 version of the server. Set that as the active project and launch it. On the command line, you navigate to that folder and just do 'dotnet run'. Make sure you have the parameters set the way you want in the appsettings.json file

Comment: Almost there!. Launched the R4 Web in debug mode. Which launches & attempts to connect to browser on https://localhost:44348/.
This times out. When I breakpoint in "FhirDocumentClientInitialize.cs", I see a refereence to "https://localhost:8081".
Is there a there a prerequisite to have an Azure Cosmos Emulator running? ( Emulator seems to require Windows 10 at a minimum & I run windows 7)  
Can I connect to an remote Azure Cosmos instance (which I have set up)? Where can I set this configuration in the project?

Comment: If you run the Cosmos version of the service, then yes, you need either an emulator or you need to connect to a remote instance of CosmosDB. You can configure your connection string for that cosmos db in appsettings.json.